Can wal_level be set to logical for both pitr recovery and logical replication?
My database cluster currently uses logical replication with wal_level set to logical. How can I integrate Point-In-Time Recovery (PITR) into this setup without changing the wal_level? If it's possible, I would also like to know any potential drawbacks of this approach.

Min WAL requirement for archiving is REPLICA, and LOGICAL>REPLICA. Since you already using logical replication with wal_level=logical, you only need to setup backups and wal archiving for PITR. For archiving you may use
archive_mode=on
archive_command=" "
archive_timeout="" #based on your RPO 

